# Alternative Definition for Injective Function?

Tags: functions, definition

I came up with an alternative definition of an injective function and would like to know if it's correct and how to prove it if it is, or why it's not correct if it isn't.

**f:A→B is injective if ∀y∈f(A) ∃! x∈A: f(x)=y**

Is this an equivalent definition to the standard "if a≠b  in A ⇒ f(a)≠f(b) in B" ?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you know any way to prove it?

Comment: Fairly sure both are taken as the "standard definition", and one can cite either of them without clarification in proofs.

Comment: The equivalence follows from the definition of **∃!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose definition 1 holds and $y=f(a)=f(b)  \in B$ for some $a,b\in A$, then we have $a=b$ by definition 1, which is the countrapositive of definition 2.

Suppose definition 2 holds and $y=f(a)\in f(A)$ then we have $x\in A$ s.t. $f(x)=y$ since $f(a)$ is in the image, the uniqueness is guaranteed by definition 2.